# Why does zsh acts different with rm !(exeption_file)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to remove all files in folder `Dowloads` except folder `no`. So I create files in `zsh`:

```
➜  Downloads touch abc.txt 1 2 3 4321 4 9; mkdir a b c no 
➜  Downloads ls
1  2  3  4  4321  9  a  abc.txt  b  c  no
```

Then I try to remove all folders and files in current folder exept folder `no` (while in `zsh`):

```
➜  Downloads rm -rf -v !(no)
zsh: unknown sort specifier
```

Then I switch to bash and try same command:

```
➜  Downloads bash
vladyslav@kdeneonlinux:~/Downloads$ rm -rf -v !(no)
removed '1'
removed '2'
removed '3'
removed '4'
removed '4321'
removed '9'
removed directory 'a'
removed 'abc.txt'
removed directory 'b'
removed directory 'c'
vladyslav@kdeneonlinux:~/Downloads$ ls
no
vladyslav@kdeneonlinux:~/Downloads$ exit
exit
➜  Downloads ls
no
➜  Downloads
```

So, in `bash` it did what I wish it to do in `zsh`. Why `zsh` says

```
zsh: unknown sort specifier
```

?

How to fix `rm !(stuff)` to work in `zsh` as in `bash`?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with `rm`. Just that in bash `!(list)` are all the files that are not in the list. While zsh do not have this syntax. Different shells, different syntax. That would be as asking why C doesn't understand `(+ 1 2)` syntax of Scheme, and how to make it do so.

Comment: This won't work by default in bash either, you need to enable extended glob syntax first with `shopt -s extglob`. You may have that automated in one of the bash initialization scripts (like ~/.bashrc).

Comment: @chrslg Oh, I thought zsh is like bash but with cooller look, I was wrong. Can`t believe it has different symtax. Thanks.

Comment: What would be the point in inventing two programming languages with exactly the same syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh, you could use

```
setopt extendedglob
rm *~no
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you give link to something or explain this syntax? So I could do some hard exeptions files by myself with zsh.

Comment: @VladyslavRehan : Do a _man zshall_ and search for the chapter _FILENAME GENERATION_.  In the sub-section _Glob Operators_, it explains the expression _x~y_ (you have to scroll down quite a lot, as this section is huge).... If my proposed solution works for you, please consider accepting it.